# Why PHPass function not working here?

Tags: php, mysql, phpass

I'm successfuly registering with phpass but login authentication is not working.Please help me.It has been 3 days ,I'm scracting my head on this error.

Register function(successfuly working and adding slashed password in database like "$2a$08$fpFjM
")

Comment: PHP-ass.. cracks me up every time :)

Comment: I always wonder if the naming was intentional, or is just like the hyphenated name of that Company before it added the hyphen

Comment: @CutyPie, on a more serious note, please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

why are you using phpass? its due to be dropped support soon... plus the cool features within php 5.5+ are awsome!

you could use password_hash/password_verify

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

example

```
<?PHP

$password = "iamcool";
$hashed = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // you can use becryt if you want to rather than password_default..

$verify = password_verify($password,$hashed);

if($verify == true){
echo "success login stuff here..";
}else{
echo "you entered the wrong info";
}

?>
```